# Bad jpg rendering on ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jpeg

I have an interactive floorplan HTML file that I am working on. It is basically a bunch of buttons overlayed over top of an image of the floor plan. My problem is that the background image looks terrible when the file is opened in IE/Edge but looks great when opened in chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Chrome:

[image: Chrome Render]

IE:

[image: IE Render]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the IE specific CSS:

img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }